# How do I know which YAML configuration I need for my Web App (App servce)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to setup CI for my web app and I have the pipeline setup in ADO, but I don't see my changes reflecting on the web app. I suspect I don't have my YAML file configured and not sure which example is the best for me to follow.

- Publishing model - Code
- Runtime Stack - Dotnet - v6.0
- Windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: `Which yaml to use` as in? The MS link which you shared has an [Example: Deploy a .NET app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example-deploy-a-net-app) yaml.

Comment: You can check out one more reference - https://devops.com/deploying-into-azure-app-service-using-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline/

Comment: @Arko that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working.

One thing I found was that my virtual directory was configured to the wrong location. It needed to be `site\wwwroot`. I also needed to update my YAML to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory )/src` and `includeRootFolder = false`

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy the **`.Net 6.0 app`** correctly via **`Azure Devops yaml pipeline`**, Refer the steps below:-

I pushed my code to Azure Repos like below:-

[image]

Click on **`1)Set up build > Starter Pipeline`** ***OR*** **`2)Pipelines on the left > New Pipeline > Azure repos git > Select your Azure repository that contains the .Net 6.0 App. > Starter Pipeline:-`**

***Add the below YAML pipeline for the Web app deployment:-***

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxxxxfd-e2b6exxxxxxx2a7)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'valeywebapp'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

[image]

**Click on** **Save and run and Save and run to run the pipeline**, The Web app will be deployed to Azure Web app successfully like below:-

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

Now, ***`I made a change in my **`.Net 6.0 Web app`** and visit the previous pipeline >  Click on run new > the deployment got triggered successfully`***:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm trying something similar to the above, but the build fails 
`##[error]No web project was found in the repository. Web projects are identified by presence of either a web.config file, wwwroot folder in the directory, or by the usage of Microsoft.Net.Web.Sdk in your project file. You can set Publish web projects property to false (publishWebProjects: false in yml) if your project doesn't follow this convention or if you want to publish projects other than web projects.`

Comment: Did you my yaml pipeline as it is for build and deploy? no project found means, Your build pipeline is unable to find sln file or project in your azure repos